# Simple neural network in Julia

Tags: python, neural-network, julia

I am try to rewrite code from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/technology-invention-and-more/how-to-build-a-simple-neural-network-in-9-lines-of-python-code-cc8f23647ca1#.ypjkfofwp) on python to julia and getting unexpected result - `[0.5; 0.5; 0.5; 0.5]` I look to the line again and again but not see difference.

Python code:

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot
training_set_inputs = array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
training_set_outputs = array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T
random.seed(1)
synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1
for iteration in xrange(10000):
    output = 1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(training_set_inputs, synaptic_weights))))
    synaptic_weights += dot(training_set_inputs.T, (training_set_outputs - output) * output * (1 - output))
print 1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(array([1, 0, 0]), synaptic_weights))))
```

My julia code:

```
function activate(x)
    return 1./(1+exp(-x))
end

function g_activate(x)
    return x.*(1-x)
end

function test(iter)

Input = [0 0 1;0 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]
TInput = transpose(Input)
Test = [0, 1, 1, 0]
Weights = 2 * rand(3, 1) - 1

for i in 1:iter

output = activate(Input*Weights)
error = Test - output
delta = error.*g_activate(output)
Weights +=  TInput*delta

end

println(activate(Input*Weights))
end
```

What I am doing wrong and how do it more idiomatic way in Julia

Comment: @khelwood, yes. It is transpose of matrix.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: I edited with another syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong input data in Julia code. To match the Python example

```
Input = [0 0 1;0 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1]
```

should be

```
Input = [0 0 1;1 1 1;1 0 1;0 1 1]
```

That's what I'm getting with corrected input:

```
julia> test(10000)
[0.00966854; 0.992117; 0.993589; 0.00786553]
```

And if I'm running Python code with `training_set_inputs = array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])` I'm getting `[ 0.5]`.